# django, ident previous page for usage in a template

Tags: django-templates

I want my page content to vary depending on which page the user came from. 
How is it possible to define the previous page to use it in a template? 
I mean it should look like

```
{% if (previous page)=="/some/page/"%}
do something
{% endif %}
```

What do I have to write instead of (previous page)?
I wonder if I can use request.META['HTTP_REFERER'] somehow, because all my attempts called errors.

Answer (score 0):

Django's template language is NOT Python and doesn't support the Python's subscript syntax. You have to use `request.META.HTTP_REFERER` as documented here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#variables

Also the http referer meta is not necessarily reliable so you might be safest using sessions to track your users navigation.